# getApplicationContext() and getSystemService() error Java

Tags: java

Alright so this may already be a thread but I still have yet to find a thread that answers my questions!

this is my code.

```
     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext()
     .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

So I get an error on"getApplicationContext()"and".getSystemService()" because I don't think they're defined or anything like that but I wouldn't know what to do or where to go to define it...?

someone help pls

This is the actual code for this method:

```
       @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String message = myArrayList.get(position);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View myLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_activity, null);
    TextView messageTextView = (TextView) myLayout.findViewById(R.id.chat_function);
    messageTextView.setText(message);
    convertView = myLayout;
    return convertView;
```

and the error is simple and it's basically "Cannot resolve method etc etc" but I don't really know what to do now knowing that that's the error!!

Comment: Read the error message, it will tell you the issue.

Comment: Could you share a [mcve] and the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: check the edited post

Comment: Unless the error message contains stuff you can not share, you should copy-paste it in it's entirety without modification and put it inside quotes; anything else hampers it's (otherwise tremendous) value.

Comment: Please use the minimal amount of text (including context, conversation and even code) in your question; aim for helping people understand in 30secs or less if they can help you or not.